# Getting an error : "OptionError: 'You can only set the value of existing options'" in python

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plotly

I am getting an error:

> "OptionError: 'You can only set the value of existing options'"

after using the below code, please can someone help?

```
### Data Analaysis
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
### Data Visualization
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import plotly.graph_objs as go 
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline, BSpline
%matplotlib inline
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=Warning)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"
```

Comment: Please post the full error message and stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

The option error "you can only set the value of existing options" are coming because of your last line of script

```
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"
```

where you are trying to update your pandas backend plotting method.

Please update your pandas and plotly packages. Because it only works with ***pandas version>=0.25*** and ***plotly version>=4.8.***
So update both the packages, restart your kernel, if you are working on Jupyter notebook. For upgrading the packages

```
pip install -U pandas
pip install -U plotly
```